# Vim synax colors are off for certain files

Tags: linux, vim

For some reason I don't have syntax color highlighting for certain configuration files.

Namely, for /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

At the same time, nginx configuration files in /etc/nginx/sites-available/ directory do have color highlighting.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

P.S. It worked after some changes in .vimrc:

filetype on

au BufNewFile,BufRead *.conf set filetype=conf

Thanks for everyone's help!

Comment: what filetype is vim using for the problem files? `:set ft?` you can also set the filetype manually if that's the problem like this `:set ft=whatever`.

Answer (score 1):

For that file that's properly highlighted,

```
:verbose setlocal filetype?
```

will tell you the *filetype*, and also from where it is set. Apparently, that *filetype detection* rules doesn't cover the other file pattern / location. You can easily add that, though, so that in the future, these files will be properly detected, too. `:help new-filetype` has all the information.